# Async drill down not working for area charts

Tags: angular, asynchronous, highcharts, ionic3, drilldown

I have implemented the drill down import like so in app.module.ts. It seems to be working fine for synchronous drill down but not for asynchronous drill down. I have created 2 pages in the ionic app. One for synchronous drill down and another one for asynchronous drill down. I am using the same app.module.ts for both the pages. Drill down seems to be working fine for synchronous drill down but not for asynchronus drill down.

```
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

declare let require: any;
export function highchartsFactory() {
  const hc = require('highcharts');
  const dd = require('highcharts/modules/drilldown');
  dd(hc);
  return hc;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    App2Page
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    App2Page,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    HttpClientModule,
    // DashboardProvider
    {
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory
    }
  ]
})
```

is this the right way to import the drilldown library in ionic? in app2.ts(in the ionic page) i am doing it like below:

```
const Highcharts = require('highcharts');
```

But the drill down is not working. The same import statements seem to be working fine for synchronous drilldown.
Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mrunalini, it looks like the module is correctly imported. Probably the problem is how you do asynchronus drill down. Please look at the basic examples of async drilldown: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/ and synchronous drill down: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/

Comment: I am doing asynchrnous drill down as depicted in jsfiddle only. There is no difference. I don't know why it is not working for asynchrnous drilldown in area charts.

Comment: Could you share your code or create some online example (for example on: https://stackblitz.com/). It will be much easier to help you.